# Plone Conditional - If Content Type is Versionable

Tags: plone, plone-4.x

Is there a simple way to check if a content-type, or a specific object, has Versioning enabled/disabled in Plone (4.3.2)?

For context, I am making some unique conditionals around portal_actions. So instead of checking `path('object/@@iterate_control').checkout_allowed()`, I need to first see if versioning is even enabled. Otherwise, the action in question does not display for items that have versioning disabled, because obviously it isn't checkout_allowed.

I didn't have any luck with good ole Google, and couldn't find this question anywhere here, so I hope it's not a dupe. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get this working by creating a new script, importing `getToolByName`, and checking current content type against `portal_repository.getVersionableContentTypes()`. Then just included that script in the conditional.

I was looking for something like this that already existed, so if anyone knows of one let me know. Otherwise, I've got my own now. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that `checkout_allowed` does is check if the object in question supports versioning at all:

```
if not interfaces.IIterateAware.providedBy(context):
        return False
```

(the interface being `plone.app.iterate.interfaces.IIterateAware`:

```
class IIterateAware( Interface ):
    """An object that can be used for check-in/check-out operations.
    """
```

The semantics `Interface.providedBy(instance)` are a bit unfortunate for usage in conditions or TAL scripts, because you'd need to import the interface, but there's a reversal helper:

```
context.portal_interface.objectImplements(context, 
                                          'plone.app.iterate.interfaces.IIterateAware')
```

Comment: That's kind of what I thought, couldn't figure out how to check without importing something. Didn't know about objectImplements though, I'll try that out. Would you suggest this solution over mine of checking getVersionableContentTypes? Not sure if either is better or less work on the server.